# How should i save photos with php/apache?

Tags: php, apache, file-management

My question is, where should i save photos that will be uploaded from the users?
my root dir for the server is
`C:/apache`
here i have the folder that contains the php files `C:/apache/htdocs` . I was wondering where should i save the files, i heard it will be better if i saved it somewhere else than the htdocs (folder that contains the php scripts), but here is the thing. If i save it directly to `C:/apache` then i can't access the photos. While saving it to a new folder in `C:/apache/htdocs/photos` would make the photos folder visible or accesible from the php pages. Is there a way i can save them somewhere else, like, let's say one folder up from the htdocs folder?

**EDIT**: the .htaccess seems like a good solution. Though i'm curious about this 1 thing:
I was thinking, is it possible to have directories something like this?

```
--->phpfiles           
    |--->index.php       
    |--->another.php   
--->photos    
    |--->1.jpg       
    |--->etc.jpg
```

And still somehow link those photos to my php files? Like making the server only view the phpfiles folder for links and all of that (so i can go to localhost/index.php and not localhost/phpfiles/index.php ) ?

**EDIT 2:** My server root is `C:/apache`, while my Document Root is `C:/apache/htdocs`. in case of any misunderstanding, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest putting the uploads in a folder like you suggested with `C:/apache/htdocs/photos` and place a .htaccess in that file that prevents direct access to the folder. That way the folder won't be visible and they can't access the images without the file name.

Another solution would be to upload the images on a third party server.

Comment: Yea, that seems like a good solution. I was thinking, is it possible to have directories something like this?
```--->phpfiles  
        |--->index.php  
        |--->another.php  
--->photos  
        |--->1.jpg  
        |--->etc.jpg  
```
And still somehow link those photos to my php files? Like making the server only view the phpfiles folder for links and all of that (so i can go to `localhost/index.php` and not `localhost/phpfiles/index.php` ) ?

Comment: @DragosPolifronie that is possible but not recommended (I have never seen somebody doing it that way). The most common solution is having a folder called 'Uploads' for example and in that folder another folder called 'Photos' for example. Or directly in the folder 'Photos'.

Comment: Hmm, why not? I mean, is it better to just leave the php files in the root directory and in the same place to have a folder named uploads where the server will store the images? I thought it would be somewhat safer having the php files in another directory

Comment: There are no security benefits in having the PHP files in a separate folder since you place the uploads in a separate folder (and you can control the access on this folder separately). Some might place certain PHP files in separate folder in order to have a better overview of the directory.

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you. So, there is no need to worry about the folder. That spares me some time and trouble

Comment: update: I used an .htaccess file where i put `deny from all` . The problem is, now i can't use the photos that users uploaded (a simple `<img src="uploads/photo1"` doesn't show the image on page, instead, it shows that thumbnail of an image that doesn't exist)

Comment: @DragosPolifronie you don't need to add the deny for all, you've to add: `Options -Indexes`

Comment: nvm, it worked, it seems it was a problem with my .conf file cause i did not include htaccess files. Thanks